# Dynamically resolve to reference cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to dynamically resolve the value from cursor something like below.

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE test(
PI_JANUS_ID IN VARCHAR2,
PO_dummy out Types.CursorType
)AS
PO_ACTUALCUROSR Types.CursorType;
cur_row tab%ROWTYPE;
val1 varchar2(100);
val2 varchar2(200);
BEGIN
 open PO_ACTUALCUROSR for select * from tab;

  LOOP
    FETCH PO_ACTUALCUROSR into cur_row;
    EXIT WHEN PO_ACTUALCUROSR%NOTFOUND;
    val1 := 'TNAME';
    SELECT 'cur_row.'||val1 INTO val2 FROM DUAL;
    dbms_output.put_line('Column Value ' || val2); 
  END LOOP ;
  CLOSE PO_ACTUALCUROSR;
END;
```

Here if you see I have to call cur_row. to get the value  but here I have the column name in a variable (val1). So how will I take the value from the cursor.

If I execute the above block I would see "cur_row.TNAME" but I actually need the value in the cursor.

Is there a way of doing this.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't really see the point, because both val1 and val2 are local variables declared inside your procedure (there are not even parameters) so why they cannot be directly included in the 'SELECT * FROM tab' query upon which your cursor (PO_ACTUALCUROSR) operates?

Comment: This is just an example I gave, my actual issue is I am having a cursor but I will know what column to pick from the cursor at run time only as I pick the column names from a different table.

Comment: Also to add the source table from where I get the cursor has 550 columns.

Comment: why don't you write `SELECT cur_row.TNAME INTO val2 FROM DUAL;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just do

```
BEGIN
 open PO_ACTUALCUROSR for select * from tab;

  LOOP
    FETCH PO_ACTUALCUROSR into cur_row;
    EXIT WHEN PO_ACTUALCUROSR%NOTFOUND;
    val2 := cur_row.tname;
    dbms_output.put_line(val2);
  END LOOP ;
  CLOSE PO_ACTUALCUROSR;
end;
```

or

```
dbms_output.put_line(cur_row.tname);
```

directly will also work.

p.s. your variable

```
val2 varchar2(200);
```

is better as

```
val2 tab.tname%type;
```

if you're saying you need to dynamically pull columns without knowing the column name ahead of time you'd have to use dynamic sql, and as you're using a pl/sql array, we need to put that in a package spec so that we can reference it (as you cannot pass pl/sql only types into dynamic SQL).

```
SQL> create table tab(id number, col1 varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into tab values (1, 'a');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> create package global_var
  2  as
  3    cur_row tab%rowtype;
  4  end;
  5  /

Package created.

SQL> declare
  2  po_actualcurosr sys_refcursor;
  3  val1 varchar2(10) := 'COL1';
  4  val2 tab.col1%type;
  5  begin
  6   open po_actualcurosr for select * from tab;
  7
  8     loop
  9             fetch po_actualcurosr into global_var.cur_row;
 10             exit when po_actualcurosr%notfound;
 11             execute immediate 'begin :a := global_var.cur_row.'||dbms_assert.simple_sql_name(val1)||'; end;' using out val2;
 12             dbms_output.put_line(val2);
 13     end loop ;
 14     close po_actualcurosr;
 15  end;
 16  /
a

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: This is a perfect answer. My problem got resolved. Thanks a ton